# Is it possible that the array map is too little for contain about 2000 items?

Tags: java, android

In my code i had caught data from a JSON file, 
I executed the program, it stopped but didn't crash.

i've tried to change json file. I found one that is Smaller than the first one and so the program works.

this JSON file is made of data o premier legue(England) and contain 3 mainly data, the name, a key and a code of the squads.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialog caric;
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public ArrayMap<Integer, Valori> ArrayDati = new ArrayMap<>();



    Button buttonProg;
    TextView textViewProg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonProg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textViewProg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    buttonProg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    new JsonCLASS().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2015-16/en.1.clubs.json");

     }
        });

}


private class JsonCLASS extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
 @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
     super.onPreExecute();


    caric = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    caric.setMessage("Please wait");
    caric.setCancelable(false);
    caric.show();
 }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();


        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   
        }

        return buffer.toString();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     super.onPostExecute(result);


     try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray Arr = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("clubs"));

            for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length(); i++){

             JSONObject jsonPart = Arr.getJSONObject(i);


              ArrayDati.put(i,new Valori( jsonPart.getString("key"), jsonPart.getString("name"), jsonPart.getString("code")));
              textViewProg.setText(textViewProg.getText()+"key : "+ ArrayDati.get(i).Key
                     +"\n"+textViewProg.getText()+"name : "+ ArrayDati.get(i).Name
                     +"\n"+textViewProg.getText()+"code : "+ ArrayDati.get(i).Code );

         }

       } catch (Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
       }


      if (caric.isShowing()) {
        caric.dismiss();
      }


  }


}
}
```

And a class to pass the data

```
public class Valori {



    String Key;
    String Name;
    String Code;


    public Valori(String key, String name,  String code) {

        this.Key  = key;
        this.Name  = name;
        this.Code = code;
    }

}
```

With this code the application stops but it doesn't close.

Comment: Read your logcat.

Comment: I can't see any obvious reason. But storing 2000 entries in an array list is no problem at all. As long as you have enough memory you could store many many more entries if you wished to.

Comment: mh ok and then where is the problem? Sorry but i don't understand where the code is wrong.